KDE applications configuration - how do they do it?
I've been tackling a project more seriously lately, a project that probably every Linux dev goes through at some point - dotfiles management.
KDE (and it's applications) has a history of resisting having it's configuration files being managed in a version control system.
That is because KDE's config files are not exactly gathered all in one place and they are also not intended to be manually edited, i.e. they are autogenerated.
Here is a git repo listing some of KDE's own config files: https://github.com/shalva97/kde-configuration-files
And when trying to configure specific applications like Konsole we also have a few, for example
~/.local/share/kxmlgui5/konsole/konsoleui.rc
~/.local/share/kxmlgui5/konsole/sessionui.rc
~/.local/share/knewstuff3/konsole.knsregistry
although I am not sure at all on what these do, more importantly though there is also:
~/.config/konsolerc
and the profile specific config files location in:
~/.local/share/konsole/
in which also Konsole colorscheme files are located.
I have put the profile and colorscheme files in my repo, but for konsolerc that wouldn't work, as it changes depending on stuff like what my display setup is for example. But there is an alternative:
using the command kwriteconfig5 or kwriteconfig6 (depending on if using plasma5 or plasma6) you can generate the file.
This works-ish. There are some settings I must have missed, as Konsole does not look quite the same on all my machines.
How do then distros like Manjaro, Kubuntu or OpenSUSE customize their KDE versions, do they use something like konsave (https://github.com/Prayag2/konsave) to export all KDE settings or do they use kwriteconfig, or some other way entirely?
Or more generally speaking, where can you find some documentation on commands like kwriteconfig, KDE config files and/or other customization options?
In the future I would like to version control (or generate using a script) the config files for Dolphin and qt theming, but it's really hard to find out where you can find stuff like that.
